# is there a command powershell command that tells whether RDP is enabled, and or being used etc?

Tags: windows, powershell, shell, system-administration

like a status/info command? something like ipconfig but RDP related.
The closest I got to is this

```
Get-Service -Name "Remote Desktop Services", "Remote Desktop Configuration", "Remote Desktop Services UserMode Port Redirector"
```

but doesnt this just say whether there is an active RDP session running?

Comment: `quser | select-string rdp`

Answer (score 1):

To **determine if RDP connections to the local machine are enabled in principle** (based on this [helpful techdirectarchive.com blog post](https://techdirectarchive.com/2021/10/03/is-rdp-enabled-how-to-enable-and-disable-remote-desktop-in-windows-10-and-11-for-all-users-or-selected-users-via-cmd-powershell-control-panel-and-windows-settings/)):

```bash
$rdpEnabled = 
  0 -eq (Get-ItemPropertyValue 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server' fDenyTSConnections)
```

To **determine if there are currently active RDP connections to the local machine** (building on [js2010](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6654942/js2010)'s helpful comment):

```bash
$rdpSessionsPresent = 
  quser.exe | Select-String -Quiet '\brdp-'
```

Comment: when I paste the first bit into PS, i get no output :(

Comment: @Cezar, both commands produce no output by design: they store output _in a (Boolean) variable. If you only run the 2nd line of each, you should see output. The first command could _fail_, namely if the registry key or value doesn't exist (it should), but then you'd see output - namely an _error message_ - either way. Do you see an error message?